# Fast algorithm for computing the similarity between two arrays

Tags: algorithms

Suppose there are two arrays (They have the same length), I want to give a quantitative description about the similarity between them. I define a formula like this, which means we can shuffle them arbitrarily. If we use the stupidest method, i.e. calculate every possible result, we need to keep array B unchanged and keep shuffling array A. There should be $n!$ kinds of $\sum (A_i-B_j)^2$
. (Because there are $n!$ different orders for array A.)

But is there any fast algorithm for it?
$$
\min_{\text{$\sigma$ permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$}} \sum_{1\le i\le n}(A_i-B_{\sigma(i)})^2
$$

Comment: You could sort the arrays and only take the difference of the corresponding elements.

Comment: As far as I understand you have $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ as two same length vectors with $n$ elements, and you want to know how close are these two vectors right? So, instead of doing this strange calculation by shuffling, I recommend to use $L^{2}$ norm defined as: $$\epsilon_{2} = \sqrt{(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B})(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B})^{T}}$$

Comment: @Tyberius What if they contain complex numbers? (Granted, you may argue that they are not complex because OP did not put a modulus around that square, but the problem makes sense also for complex numbers.)

Comment: @AloneProgrammer OP wants to find the distance up to permutations, if I understand correctly. Assume the array contains pairs of close numbers, but they are shuffled randomly, for instance.

Comment: Welcome to SciComp, DingDong. Why would you want to shuffle? Is there an underlying effect that shuffles the compared arrays? If not, then the L2 norm proposed earlier should be correct.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I'm not sure what to do in the case of complex numbers or more generally points in an N-dimensional space. I believe it would be equivalent to the seemingly much harder problem of taking two set of points and forming pairs with one element of each set such that the overall sum of squared distances was minimized.

Comment: @Tyberius Now that you put it that way, it sounds a lot like an instance of the [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), which is solvable in $O(n^3)$. Maybe though one can do better than that, since here essentially the number of degrees of freedom of the problem is $O(n)$, not $O(n^2)$.

Comment: OP: if you confirm that this is what you meant, we can fix up that formula which currently does not work at all.

Comment: Sorry for my delay. I have read all your comments and thanks a lot for your help.
I mean, suppose there are two ordered arrays A and B. We can shuffle them arbitrarily and turn them into $A'$ and $B'$. Actually my question was, is there any possibility that $(A-B)(A-B)^T$>$(A'-B')(A'-B')^T$?
By the way, it is my first time to learn about the Hungarian algorithm, which is interesting. Thank you all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can formulate this problem as an assignment problem of the form

$\min \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} w_{i,j}x_{i,j}$

subject to

$\sum_{j=1}^{n}  x_{i,j}=1,\; i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i,j}=1, \; j=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$x_{i,j}=\mbox{0 or 1} \; i=1, 2, \ldots, n, j=1, 2, \ldots, n.$

Basically, $x_{i,j}=1$ if column $i$ of $A$ is matched with column $j$ of $B$ and $0$ otherwise.  The constraints ensure that each column of $A$ is matched with exactly one column of $B$.

Here, you would let

$w_{i,j}=\| A_{i} - B_{j} \|_{2}^{2}, i=1, 2, \ldots, n, j=1, 2, \ldots, n.$

Once you've precomputed the weights (which might well be the most time consuming step if the matrices have many more rows than columns), the well known Hungarian algorithm can solve this assignment problem in $O(n^{3})$ time.  A number of more sophisticated algorithms are available that have even better asymptotic complexity.  Depending on the size of your matrices, it might or might not be worthwhile to use one of these more sophisticated methods.

Comment: Thanks. I believe it is feasible. Another question is just like what I commented above, suppose there are two ordered arrays $A$ and $B$. We can shuffle them arbitrarily and turn them into $A′$ and $B′$. Is there any possibility that $(A−B)(A−B)^T>(A′−B′)(A′−B′)^T$? I tried some instances, but I didn't find any arrays that could meet the requirements above.

Comment: I’m sorry, but your notation is unclear.  Our A and B matrices or vectors?  What do you mean by X > Y when X and Y are matrices?

Comment: I mean A and B are arrays, which can also be taken as row vectors. For example, $A=[a_1\ a_2 \cdots a_n], B=[b_1\ b_2\cdots b_n]$.

Answer (score 0):

You have a $1D$ minimization problem and not an $argmin$-problem. Here, you could easily use a 1-Wasserstein distance (commonly known as the Earth mover's distance). For the 1-dimensional case, there is a closed form solution compute-able in linear time. I'll write more when I have the time.

Comment: Are you saying that the Wasserstein distance gives the solution of *that* minimum problem, or that it can be used to formulate another (different) similarity measure that could suit OP's needs? It is not clear from your answer.